# detect if a form is submitted with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, submit

Is there a way to detect if a form is submitted? Im trying to set a class based on a custom validation something like below example, is that possible?

```
  .control-group{ :class => ("error" if form_is_submitted ) }
```

Now trying :

```
  .control-group{ :class => ("error" if params[:user][:profile_attributes][:gender] == nil) }
```

This fails if the form is not submitted because then the params are nill and throws an error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your form data is submitted through fields with `name` attributes like `user[profile_attributes][gender]` *(all having the `user` prefix)*, you can check if the `:user` exists in `params`.

```
... if params.include?(:user)
```

If for some reason *(like coming from the route)* `params[:user]` is already going to have a value even for `GET` requests, you can look for a specific form field having a value. For example, you could add a hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :some_field, :value => true %>
```

and check for **it** in your condition

```
... if params[:user].include?(:some_field)
```

---

You can alternatively check if the request is via the `POST` method

```
... if request.post?
```

This works for other methods as well, like `request.put?` for an update method.

Comment: aah great I was really stuck on this one, the check if the page is posted works great ! thx a lot